# z-index issues with CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

First time posting here, have long used the site as a resource for any problems I come across but for the first time I haven't been able to fix my code using previous answers.

There's probably a very simple answer for what I'm asking and I'm just missing something.

I am trying to create a snippet that I can use in a production site soon. I want to create an image "frame" that sits around an image. I also then want this frame to be animated and swing from side to side.

Before I insert the animation code, the code is as below, and works perfectly (the frame is above the image).

```
.frame {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-left: 35%;
    display: inline-flex;
    background-image: url(http://www.studiopastimes.info/tester/images/frame.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 3rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.internal-frame {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    z-index:-5;
}
.internal-frame img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, when I add the animation code, this breaks the z-index.

```
@-webkit-keyframes swinging{
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    33%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
    66%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
}

@keyframes swinging{
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    33%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
    66%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
}

.swingimage{
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-animation: swinging 5s ease-in-out ;
    animation: swinging 5s ease-in-out ;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

This can all be seen in the Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMrrWB

Any idea how I can get the CSS animation to work, whist still having the frame above the image? I understand from my research there issues with CSS animations and z-index, but I couldn't get any of the suggested fixes to work. Any help would be great and if there's any issues with how I have asked this question please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to move the image behind the frame?  https://jsfiddle.net/jd2j3qLe/1/

Comment: Hi Pete. No, the photo and frame are supposed to swing together, as it would if it was a real picture in a frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put the frame on a pseudo-element:

```css
.frame {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-left: 35%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 69.25%;  /* this is the aspect ratio of the image: height / width */
  position: relative;
}

.frame:after {
  content:''; 
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url(http://www.studiopastimes.info/tester/images/frame.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;           /* match the padding */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swinging {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swinging {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
}

.swingimage {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-animation: swinging 5s ease-in-out;
  animation: swinging 5s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame swingimage">
  <img src="http://www.studiopastimes.info/tester/images/cabaret.jpg" class="img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index` property needs the element to have a set position. then if you just add `position: relative;` to your `.frame` it'll make the job.

full css :

```
.frame {
        margin-top: 5rem;
        margin-left: 35%;
    display: inline-flex;
        position: relative;
        background-image: url(http://www.studiopastimes.info/tester/images/frame.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative
        z-index: 10;
        padding: 3rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
/*      height: 10rem;
            width: 20rem;*/
}
.internal-frame {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
    z-index:-5;
}
.internal-frame img {
        width: 100%;
  z-index:-5;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swinging{
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    33%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
    66%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
}

@keyframes swinging{
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    33%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
    66%{-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
}

.swingimage{
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-animation: swinging 5s ease-in-out ;
    animation: swinging 5s ease-in-out ;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

with your html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FRAME TESTER</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="frame">
    <div class="internal-frame">
<img src="http://www.studiopastimes.info/tester/images/cabaret.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried that before and it didn't work. See codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMrrWB